# Make xargs symlinks with return of a command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xargs

Im trying made a symlink file with name returned in a previous command but return the error `is not a directory`.

Each file in a folder i want to made the symlink file with the `hash.0`, the Following code snippet  is in example file `213123.0`:

```
for x in *; do openssl x509 -noout -hash -in $x|xargs ln -s $x {} ;  done;
```

Returned:

```
"ln: target ‘b28afb7c’ is not a directory"
```

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xargs` is not `find`. You do not need `{}` to tell xargs where to stick the argument it always just sticks it at the end. Drop the `{}` argument and your command will work.

Use of `xargs` `-t` argument to have it show you the command it was trying to run would have found this for you.

It should also be pointed out that `openssl` (at least in some versions) has a c_rehash perl script that does this for you and handles corner cases that naive attempts will not (such as duplicated certificate files and duplicate hash results). Additionally your snippet doesn't actually append the `.0` you said you wanted.

You cannot use xargs to do what you want here as you cannot control the placement/etc. of the argument to `xargs` such as to create the `hash.0` filename you desire. That being said `xargs` is entirely unnecessary here as you only have a single bit of output to deal with.

Either use `hash=$(openssl ... "$x"); ln -s "$x" "${hash}.0"` or drop the variable entirely and use `ln -s "$x" "$(openssl ... "$x")"`.

Comment: this works: for x in *; do  openssl x509 -noout -hash -in $x|xargs ln -s $x ${1} ;  done;

but this not: for x in *; do  openssl x509 -noout -hash -in $x|xargs ln -s $x "${1}.0" ;  done;

how i can concat these to generate the ln?

Comment: @CiroVargas That does not "work". That happens not to fail because the shell sees `${1}` as a variable to expand and expands it to the value of the first positional parameter (same as it would `$1`) and as it has no value it becomes an empty string and ln does not see it. You cannot do what you want with xargs. You will need to capture the result of the openssl command in a variable or use it inline with the ln command itself to do what you want.

Comment: Ooh, tnks. Fine with for x in *; do hash=$(openssl x509 -noout -hash -in $x); ln -s $x "${hash}.0" ;  done;

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel installed:

```
parallel 'ln -s {} $(openssl x509 -noout -hash -in {}).0' ::: *
```

If it is not packaged for your system, this should install it in 10 seconds:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

To learn more: Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
will love you for it.

Comment: While it is fine to recommend `parallel` instead of `xargs`, it does not address the issues in the question — it perpetuates the problems, in fact.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the heads up: The .0 is now added.